# Challenging (or not) paralelogram problem - vector as a linear combination of other vectors

Tags: analytic-geometry

I'm having the hardest time on this particular problem:

> On the paralelogram ABCD we have
>
> $\vec{DE} = \alpha \ \vec{DC}$
>
> $3 \ \vec{BF} = \vec{FC}$
>
> $G$ is the intersection between $AE$ and $DF$
>
> What is the value of $\alpha$ so that $\vec{AG} = \ 4 \vec{GE}$? Also,
>   write $\vec{w}$ as a linear combination of $\vec{u} = \vec{AB}$ and
>   $\vec{v} = \vec{AD}$.

[image: Paralelogram]

Answer (not complete)

$$
\vec{GE} + \vec{ED} + \vec{DG} = 0
$$

$$
\frac{1}{5} (\vec{v} + \alpha \vec{u}) - \alpha \vec{u} + \vec{DG} = 0
$$

If anyone can give me a hint I appreciate.

Thank you. Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can take the position of point $A$ as $\vec{0}$ without loss of generality. Take the position vectors of the points $E$,$F$ and $G$ as $\vec{e}$,$\vec{f}$ and $\vec{g}$ respectively. Now first use the conditions given in the problem.

1. $\vec{DE}=\alpha\vec{DC}\implies e=\alpha\vec{u}+\vec{v}$
2. $3 \ \vec{BF} = \vec{FC}\implies \vec{f}=\dfrac v4+u$
3. $\vec{AG} = \ 4 \vec{GE}\implies \vec{g}=\dfrac {4e}5=\frac 45(\alpha\vec{u}+\vec{v})$

Now, use the condition that $G$ lies on the line segment $DF$. This will give you the equation $\vec{g}=\lambda \vec{v}+(1-\lambda)\vec{f}$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. Compraing this with the expression for $\vec{g}$ that we found in point 3, we can find the values of $\alpha$ and $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\vec0=\vec{GE}+\vec{ED}+\vec{DG}$.  Now express those three vectors in terms of $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ and exploit their linear independence.

Comment: i know that $\vec{GE} = \frac{1}{5} (\vec{v} + \alpha \vec{u})$ and $\vec{ED} = - \alpha \vec{u}$ but what should I write for $\vec{DG}$ in a way that I don't get, after all calculations,  $0 = 0$?

Comment: I've made some edits on the question